# Determine file compression type

Tags: unzip, compression

I backed up a large number of files to S3 from a PC before switching to a Mac several months ago.  Several months later, I'm now trying to open the files and realized the files were all compressed by the S3 GUI tool I used so I can not open them.

I can't remember what program I used to upload the files and standard decompression commands from the command line are not working e.g.,

> unzip
>
> bunzip2
>
> tar -zxvf

How can I determine what the compression type is of the file?  Alternatively, what other decompression techniques can I try?

PS - I know the files are not corrupted because I tested downloading and opening them back when I originally uploaded to S3.

Comment: have to tried the `file` utility?

Comment: the output of `od -xa` for say the first 100 bytes of the file could also be helpful.

Comment: `file` is a command line tool, goto bash and type `file filename`

Comment: Can you enlighten us as to what 'S3 GUI tool' is? It may help us to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Universal Extractor (open source) to determine compression types.
Here is a link: http://legroom.net/software/uniextract/

The little downside is that it looks in the first place for the extension, but I manage to change the extensions myself for a inknown file and it works almost always, eg .rar or .exe etc..

---

EDIT:

I found a huge list of archive programs, maybe one of them will work? It's ridiciously big:

http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/summary_mf.php
http://www.maximumcompression.com/index.html

Comment: maybe the OP used UHARC compression type? It's not widely known and little used but it's the best compression method in the world, At least it was when I looked for the best one.. http://www.klaimsoft.com/winuha/

Comment: also, try http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html Unarchiver? It's for MAC. I have no MAC so I can't Test.